# javascript won't run in jquery .load function

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook-like

I have a problem with executing javascript with .load function in jquery.
In my main js file I have something like it:

```
var dt = new Date();
$(".pp_social").load("trackingCode.html?"+ dt.getTime());
```

and in trackingCode.html

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<div class="fb-like" data-href="www.blah.com" data-send="true" data-width="450"   data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

When I run it for the first time is fine.
Then any next time I invoke it, it omits javascript part.
Any ideas what coluld be wrong and why?

---

Cheers,
Bartek

Answer (score 4):

Well, your script creates an element and gives it the id value "facebook-jssdk".  There's a line at the top:

```
if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
```

Thus, once it's created the element, it'll never do anything again.

Comment: Ok. Understand. At the moment it is like button for a each photo in a gallery. What is the best method to make that part unique and working?

Comment: Well I'm not sure why you'd need to re-import the code over and over again.

Comment: Cause I didn't know how to put multiple 'I like' buttons on one site (gallery). I've already found below code and it works fine:

Comment: Cause I didn't know how to put multiple 'I like' buttons on one site (gallery). I've already found a method here: (http://raahede.com/blog/2010/10/12/multiple-facebook-like-buttons-on-one-page.aspx) and it works fine.
Thanks 4help :)